# Listings highlighting directives when indented

Tags: listings

I am using listings to highlight code snippets. These are usually a mix of C, C++, Python, assembly, and chunks of plain text. Given the set of languages I have used the [`mcode.sty` file](https://github.com/nasa/nasa-latex-docs/blob/master/support/packages/mcode/mcode.sty) as I quite like the highlighting (cf. **`pragma`**). However, when I have indented pre-processing it doesn't do correct highlighting. How can I remedy this? Having the indented pre-processing is a style I really want to keep, as I think it gives better readability.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode} 
%\lstset{language=C,
%    morecomment=[l][{\color[rgb]{0.1, 0.2, 0.8}}]{\#},
%    moredelim=[il][{\color[rgb]{0.1, 0.2, 0.8}}]{@},
%}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
#pragma omp simd /* Implemenation defined default assumed. */
for (int i = 0; i < VEC_LEN; i++)
{
    // do something
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
{
    #pragma omp simd /* Implemenation defined default assumed. */
    for (int i = 0; i < VEC_LEN; i++)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={},escapechar=@]
Some plain text I would also like formatted.
@\textbf{Important info}@
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

PS - While I like the formatting from `mcode.sty` I am not too attached to it, so will settle for a suitable substitute I can bundle in my preamble.

Comment: Workaround: `\lstset{otherkeywords={pragma,\# }}`. Note that indenting `#pragma`s and other directives is often advised against - not by me, though :)

Comment: @Marijn, the suggested work around messes with the highlighting of `#define`, and I can't then just add that to the `otherkeywords` else it is wrongly highlighted in the comment.